# Сортировка новостей

Tags: mysqli, php, сортировка, mysql

Добрый день.

Хочу выполнить сортировку новостей по дате и имени, но не получается, а точнее если ставишь в запросе `ORDER BY $order_db`, то вывод новостей вообще прекращается, а прекращается именно из-за `$order_db`, выходит ошибка. Хотя это сортировка стоит для другого, но там все работает. Вот код:

```
 /* =====Сортировка===== */
        $order_p = array(

                        'datea' => array('по дате добавления - к последним', 'date ASC'),
                        'dated' => array('по дате добавления - с последних', 'date DESC'),
                        'titlea' => array('от А до Я', 'title ASC'),
                        'titled' => array('от Я до А', 'title DESC')
                        );
        $order_get = clear($_GET['order']); // получаем возможный параметр сортировки
        if(array_key_exists($order_get, $order_p)){
            $order = $order_p[$order_get][0];
            $order_db = $order_p[$order_get][1];
        }else{
            // по умолчанию сортировка по первому элементу массива order_p
            $order = $order_p['datea'][0];
            $order_db = $order_p['datea'][1];
        }
        /* =====Сортировка===== */           
        $all_news = news($order_db);
```

---

```
function news($order_db){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT news_id, title, anons, date FROM news ORDER BY $order_db DESC LIMIT $start_pos, $perpage";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $all_news = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $all_news[] = $row;
    }
    return $all_news;
}
```

Ну и сам вывод сортировки:

```
Сортировать:&nbsp;    
            <ul id="menuuu">    
                <li><?=$order?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($order_p as $key => $value): ?>
                            <?php if($value[0] == $order) continue; ?>
                                <li><a href="ссылку потом пропишу" class="sort-bot"><?=$value[0]?></a></li>                        
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
            </ul>
```

Кто сможет найти ошибку, подскажите ее, пожалуйста. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно работать не будет, у тебя ведь в массиве ASC

```
'datea' => array('по дате добавления - к последним', 'date ASC')
```

и тут же в запросе DESC

```
ORDER BY $order_db DESC
```

И еще в запросе есть `date`, это зарезервированная функция в mysql, её нужно обернуть в кавычки:

```
`date`
```

Comment: Да уж глупая ошибка, спасибо большое)